# glfwSwapBuffers on Keystroke

Tags: c, opengl, glfw

I am currently learning OpenGL and I came across the function glfwSwapBuffers, which will swap the buffers of the window. Out of pure curiosity, I thought, can I swap the buffers on keystrokes. So I tried it and I found out that glfwSwapBuffers does not swap buffers on every keystroke. Here is my code

```
void kback();

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow *w = glfwCreateWindow(700, 550, "Terminal", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(w);

    glewInit();

    glfwSetCharCallback(w, kback);

    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(w)){
        glfwPollEvents();
        glFlush();
        glFinish();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

int c = 0;

void kback(struct GLFWwindow *w, unsigned int code){
    printf("Press : %d : %c \r", c, code);
    fflush(stdout);
    glfwSwapBuffers(w);
    c++;
}
```

NOTE: This code is for OpenGL 2.1.

With this code, if I run the program and press some keys, the program does not swap buffers for every keystroke. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first assume that your statement:

> the program does not swap buffers for every keystroke

is actually an interpretation of yours for a possible reason why you observe *alternating black and white* backgrounds when you hit a key.

However, `glfwSwapBuffers()` works just fine here.

The actual cause is that you only clear one of the buffers with your single `glClear()` call. The buffer, which is cleared by this call to white is the initial back/draw buffer of the window's swap chain. All other buffers will have a default color of black.

So, when the window's swap chain has two buffers, then you will see alternating black and white backgrounds of the window when you hit a key, because you never modify any of the buffers after your first `glClear()`.

This explains the observed behaviour of the program, but in order to answer what you *should be doing* we need to understand what you actually *want* to do.

You *could* move the call to `glClear()` into the window loop so that when you cycle through all buffers by key presses, each of them will eventually be cleared.

Comment: I have realized my mistake and moved the glClear call to the main loop, and it works fine now. Thank you to all who helped me